# disable/delete phpmyadmin aws ec2 lamp

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, apache-1.3

i am pretty new to dedicated hosting and aws cloud.  i was able to setup my instance with a lamp stack and installed phpmyadmin, moved it away from the 'www' directory and gave it an alias in my httpd.conf
but i've read that disabling all together and accessing and managing my dB through a client such as  MySQL Workbench would greatly improve security.

question: how would i remove / disable (which ever is best) phpmyadmin without destroying my sql dB's that i have created? the site is live and i am nervous about any disruption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do is remove the alias you configured and then restart apache.

If you installed phpmyadmin using a package manager (yum, apt-get) then put phpmyadmin back where it was originally and run the remove process for the package manager e.g.

```
apt-get remove phpmyadmin

yum remove phpmyadmin
```

etc. You can probably get away with just deleting the phpmyadmin directory tree too.

Comment: would 'yum remove phpmyadmin' affect files outside of 'phpmyadmin'? in other words does the line command affect .conf files or .ini files?

Comment: It will affect only those files in the phpmyadmin package. Use `rpm -qa | grep -i phpmyadmin` to get the phpmyadmin package name then e.g. `rpm -ql phpMyAdmin` to list all the files in the package to show what would be removed.